# GoJS event mouseDrop is not firing (use SelectedMoved)

Tags: gojs

I am trying to get GoJS event *mouseDrop* to fire when drag/drop a Node around.

I added the following events to Node:

`// ***********************************
          mouseEnter: function (e, obj) { 
            console.log("mouse enter"); },
          mouseLeave: function (e, obj) { 
            console.log("mouse leave"); },
          mouseDragEnter: function (e, node, prev) {
            console.log("mouse drag enter");
          },
          mouseDragLeave: function (e, node, next) {
            console.log("mouse drag leave");
          },
          mouseDrop: function (e, node) {
            console.log("mouse drag drop");
          },
// ***********************************`

Only the **mouseEnter** and **mouseLeave** is actually fired.

How can I get GoJs to trigger its **mouseDrop** event to fire so I can capture the new location of the Node?

Code example:  https://codepen.io/ravir_dhali/full/rNNpZmp

Answer (score 1):

My code example was not correct. When you drop a NODE on another NODE, then the mouseDrop is triggered.

However, what I am trying to do is:
When a NODE is moved on the Diagram and it is positioned/moved around and dropped, I want to grab the new Diagram location.

By using addDiagramListener > SelectionMoved I was able to get the values I needed.

```
myDiagram.addDiagramListener("SelectionMoved", function(event) {

  // https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Part.html#location
  // * PART
  var selectedNode = event.diagram.selection.first();

  console.log("selectedNode",selectedNode);
  console.log("selectedNodeKey",selectedNode.key);
  console.log("selectedNode", selectedNode.location.toString());
  console.log("selectedNode", selectedNode.location.x);
  console.log("selectedNode", selectedNode.location.y);
  console.log("locationObject", selectedNode.locationObject);

  //Save new location
  // key: selectedNode.key
  // location-x: selectedNode.location.x
  // location-y: selectedNode.location.y

});
```

Codepen updated :  https://codepen.io/ravir_dhali/full/rNNpZmp

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing event handlers only on the Nodes, I think you want to get events for the whole diagram.  Implement a "SelectionMoved" **DiagramEvent** listener: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/events.html#SelectionMoved